# What is the mean in the variational auto-encoder?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, math, autoencoders, variational-autoencoder

Here's a diagram of a variational auto-encoder.

[image]

There are 2 nodes before the sample (encoding vector). One is the *mean*, one is the *standard deviation*. The *mean* one is confusing.

Is it the mean of values or is it the mean deviation?

$$\text{mean} = \dfrac{X_i+..+X_n}{N}$$

$$\text{mean deviation} = \dfrac{[X_i|+..+|X_n|}{N}$$

Comment: Hello, I'm no expert but I assume is the Mean of the values. Usually you need the mean and the standard deviation to describe a distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of neither, although leaning towards the first definition of the Mean as a simple average of values.

It's a **distribution parameter** of the Gaussian, so it's the *expected* average of samples as the number of samples approaches infinity.

The distrinction is that you could draw three samples, -2, 0 and -1, from a Standard Normal - the mean of samples would be -1, but the *distribution* mean is still 0.

From a network architecture PoV, it's a learnable transformation applied on top of samples from a Standard Normal, so you only need to learn the transformation and get sampling for 'free'.